# knockout update unit price when product combo changes

Tags: select, knockout.js

I have this table bounded to knockout like this

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Items">
    <tr class="gradeA">
        <td>
            <select name="MaterialId" data-bind="options: $parent.lookups.materials, optionsText: 'Name', value: Material"></select></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Quantity" data-bind="value: Quantity"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="UnitPrice" data-bind="value: UnitPrice"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Discount" data-bind="value: Discount"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" data-bind="value: Price" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

javascript is:

```
function Item() {
    this.Material = ko.observable()
    this.Quantity = ko.observable(1)
    this.UnitPrice = ko.observable(0)
    this.Discount = ko.observable(0)

    this.MaterialRetailPrice = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.Material() ? this.Material().RetailPrice : 0
    }, this);
    this.StoreId = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.Store() ? this.Store().Id : 0
    }, this)
    this.Price = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.Quantity() * this.UnitPrice() - this.Discount()
    }, this)
}

function materialBuyBillViewModel() {
    var self = this
    self.lookups = {
        stores: ko.observableArray([]),
        materials: ko.observableArray([])
    }
    self.Items = ko.observableArray()

    self.VendorBill = ko.observable()
    self.Vendor = ko.observable()
    self.Discount = ko.observable()
    self.Vat = ko.observable()
//... Methods to fill lookups
}
$(document).ajaxStop(function (event, request, settings) {
    MaterialBuyBillViewModel.AddItem()
})
$(document).ready(function () {
    MaterialBuyBillViewModel = new materialBuyBillViewModel()
})
```

The result is fine and I can change the unit price and get price updated, but the missing thing is to get unit price changed and price updated when product select is changed (replace unitprice value with Material().RetailPrice). any one can point me how to bind unit price input properly?

Comment: self.AddItem = function () {
        self.Items.push(new Item())
    }

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't quite understand what the problem is. Could you rephrase the issue, using the exact variable names you're also using in code? (e.g.: I don't see `Product().RetailPrice` anywhere). Maybe you can give an example that shows the expected result for certain data?

Comment: sorry, I mean Material().RetailPrice not Product().RetailPrice

Comment: Simplify your example to the minimum needed to show your problem. You have a ton of extra stuff here that is not relevant and will turn people off from tackling this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question correctly.

You can create a `ko.computed` with a `read` and `write` method.

The read method enables you to check if a material is selected. If there is, you return the price of the selected material. If there isn't, you return the user defined `UnitPrice` value.

The write method just forwards the user input straight to the `UnitPrice` property. To indicate that, when a material is selected, the user cannot define the value, I've added a `disabled` binding on the input field.

Let me know if this solves your problem.

```js
function Item() {
  this.Material = ko.observable();
  this.Quantity = ko.observable(5);
  this.UnitPrice = ko.observable(1);
  this.Discount = ko.observable(0);

  this.ComputedUnitPrice = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
      return this.Material() ? this.Material().RetailPrice : this.UnitPrice();
    },
    write: function(val) {
      this.UnitPrice(val);
    },
    owner: this
  });


  this.Price = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.Quantity() * this.ComputedUnitPrice() - this.Discount()
  }, this);
}

function materialBuyBillViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.lookups = {
    materials: ko.observableArray([{
      Name: "Material 1",
      RetailPrice: 1
    }, {
      Name: "Material 2",
      RetailPrice: 2
    }, {
      Name: "Material 3",
      RetailPrice: 3
    }])
  };

  self.Items = ko.observableArray([
    new Item()
  ]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new materialBuyBillViewModel());
```

```css
[disabled] {
  background: #efefef
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Material</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>UnitPrice</th>
      <th>Discount</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: Items">
    <tr class="gradeA">
      <td>
        <select name="MaterialId" data-bind="options: $parent.lookups.materials, optionsText: 'Name', optionsCaption: 'Pick a material', value: Material, allowValueUnset: true"></select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Quantity" data-bind="value: Quantity">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="UnitPrice" data-bind="value: ComputedUnitPrice, disable: Material">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Discount" data-bind="value: Discount">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" data-bind="value: Price" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem except I don't need to disable unitPrice field when changing material, just to put the default price. Thanks again